# how to integrate a shared layout using Thymeleaf and use that layout in all the html pages in the project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, template-engine

what I've done so far is this,But obviously it's not working. I want to use this header and footer in all the pages, how to make a shared layout and use it in  other pages?? I have given the picture as well as the codes. Please help me with a sample code of an html page which is using the main_layout.html.

Since I'm very new to Thymeleaf there maybe stupid mistakes in the code.

Than you in advance.

[image: But obviously it's not working. I want to use this header and footer in all the pages how to make a shared layout and use it in other pages??]

HEADER.HTML

```
<header class="site-header" th:fragment="header">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="index.html" id="branding">
            <img src="/dummy/logo.png" alt="Site Title">
            <small class="site-description">Slogan goes
                here</small>
        </a> <!-- #branding -->
        <nav class="main-navigation">
            <button type="button" class="toggle-menu"><i class="fa 
          fa-bars"></i></button>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="../views/index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="../views/about.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="../views/gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="../views/download.html">Download</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="../views/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="../views/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul> <!-- .menu -->
        </nav> <!-- .main-navigation -->
        <div class="mobile-menu"></div>
    </div>
</header> <!-- .site-header -->
```

FOOTER.HTML

```
<footer class="site-footer" th:fragment="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="dummy/logo-footer.png" alt="Site Name">

        <address>
            <p>495 Brainard St. Detroit, MI 48201 <br><a href="tel:354543543">(563) 429 234 890</a> <br> <a
                    href="mailto:info@bandname.com">info@bandname.com</a></p>
        </address>

        <form action="#" class="newsletter-form">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email to 
join newsletter...">
            <input type="submit" class="button cut-corner" value="Subscribe">
        </form> <!-- .newsletter-form -->

        <div class="social-links">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
        </div> <!-- .social-links -->

        <p class="copy">Copyright 2014 Company Name. Designed by
            Themezy. All right reserved</p>
    </div>
</footer> <!-- .site-footer -->
```

MAIN_LAYOUT.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">

<head>

    <!-- Loading third party fonts -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="fonts/font-awesome.min.css" th:href="@{fonts/font- 
awesome.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Loading main css file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/ie-support/html5.js"></script>
<script src="js/ie-support/respond.js"></script>../../static/
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body class="header-collapse">

    <div id="site-content">
        <div th:replace="fragments/header::header"></div>
        <div th:replace="fragments/footer::footer"></div>
    </div> <!-- #site-content -->

    <script th:src="@{js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{js/plugins.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{js/app.js}"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

INDEX.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorate="~{fragments/main_layout}">

<head>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="hero">
        <div class="slider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li class="lazy-bg" data-background="dummy/slide-1.jpg">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h2 class="slide-title">Header goes here</h2>
                        <h3 class="slide-subtitle">Less important text goes here</h3>
                        <p class="slide-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <br>Fugiat
                            aliquid minus nemo sed est.</p>

                        <a href="#" class="button cut-corner">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="lazy-bg" data-background="dummy/slide-2.jpg">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h2 class="slide-title">Header goes here</h2>
                        <h3 class="slide-subtitle">Less important text goes here</h3>
                        <p class="slide-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <br>Fugiat
                            aliquid minus nemo sed est.</p>

                        <a href="#" class="button cut-corner">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="lazy-bg" data-background="dummy/slide-3.jpg">
                    <div class="container">.........
```

[image]
Here is the Header, footer and the layout if anyone wants to edit and post.
The index is also given here , where i'm using the layout. but the output comes like as I'm showing in the 2nd image. And whatever I'm writing inside the index page as the content, nothing shows in the output.

[image: where i'm using the layout. but the output comes like as I'm showing in the 2nd image. And whatever I'm writing inside the index page as the content, nothing shows in the output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed to specify the place for page content, inside `MAIN_LAYOUT.HTML`:

```html
<div id="site-content">
        <div th:replace="fragments/header::header"></div>
        <!-- ** div for content fragment - this was missed ** -->
        <div layout:fragment="content"> Page content </div>

        <div th:replace="fragments/footer::footer"></div>
    </div> <!-- #site-content -->
```

Also, `layout` declared above should be included in `INDEX.HTML` so that thymeleaf can parse and place your content at this `div`.

```html
<body> 
<!-- ** layout container - this was missed **-->
    <div layout:fragment="content">
    <!-- your page content -->
    </div
</body>
```

Comment: it gives error. If I keep the fragments my page is running but showing in a scattered way.

Comment: Thanks your answer helped. there's another problem. Those links in  the HEADER.HTML are not working .

Comment: @Souma : check this answer for link not working in header.html - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61700852/7505731