# Spring Boot and Thymeleaf - "a href"s to another sites going into 404 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have created a spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf project version 2.2.6-RELEASE with IntelliJ version 2020.1.
Unfortunately, I do not know why the links in the thymeleaf templates are not referring to the next ones.

When I start the project and type  "localhost:8080" in my web browser the index.html site is visible.
After clicking a "a href" inside the index.html , the web browser shows me the url e.g. "localhost:8080/product.html" with an 404 error.

Heres the project structure:
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNeDd.jpg)

The index.html file here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th ="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Naturkost Warenmanagement</title>
    <link th:href="@{/stylesheet.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Warenmanagement</h1>
        <h2>Geschenke und Naturkost</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="nav">
            <h3>Navigation</h3>

            <ul>

                <li><a th:href="@{/index.html}">Home</a></li>
                <li><a th:href="@{/product.html}">Artikel</a></li>
                <li><a th:href="@{/employee.html}">Mitarbeiter</a></li>
                <li><a th:href="@{/order.html}">Bestellung</a></li>
                <li><a th:href="@{/stockground.html}">Lager</a></li>
                <li><a th:href="@{/supplier.html}">Lieferant</a></li>
                <li><a th:href="@{/transaction.html}">Lager Transaktion</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
.
.
.
.
```

@Controller
NavigationController.class:

```
@RequestMapping("/index")
public String index() {
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping("/employee")
public String employee(){
    return "employee";
}

@RequestMapping("/order")
public String order(){
    return "order";
}

@RequestMapping("/product")
public String product(){
    return "product";
}

@RequestMapping("/stockground")
public String stockground(){
    return "stockground";
}

@RequestMapping("/supplier")
public String supplier(){
    return "supplier";
}

@RequestMapping("/transaction")
public String transaction(){
    return "transaction";
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `.html` from action:

```html
<li><a th:href="@{/index.html}">Home</a></li>
```

And keep it like :

```html
<li><a th:href="@{/index}">Home</a></li>
```

Now it will go and hit API - `localhost:8080/<action>`

And respective `.html` will be added by spring boot using view resolver.